# Without calculus, show $\tan$ is increasing at an increasing rate on $[0,\pi/2)$ and increasing at a decreasing rate on $(-\pi/2,0]$

Tags: trigonometry

We

- use unit-circle definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$, then define $\tan=\sin/\cos$;
- have the graphs of $\sin$ and $\cos$; and
- [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293101) how to show that $\tan$ is increasing.

But how do we show that the second derivative is positive on $[0,\pi/2)$ and negative on $(-\pi/2,0]$, but without using calculus/derivatives?

Comment: This is not really a well-posed question (as you say, it is not clear what it means to do something "without calculus"), but my guess is that you are not supposed to refer to derivatives at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer analyzes the case for $[0,\pi/2)$.

You can use the answer you have attached with the following identity for tangent.
$$\tan(x-y) = \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}.$$
Now, suppose that $z>x$ and $z-x = x-y$.  Then,
$$\tan(z-x) = \frac{\tan(z)-\tan(x)}{1+\tan(z)\tan(x)} = \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)} = \tan(x-y).$$

Thus,
$$\tan(z)-\tan(x) = \frac{1+\tan(x)\tan(z)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}\left[\tan(x)-\tan(y)\right].$$

Because you have already established that tangent is an increasing function (answer you have attached), we can say that $\tan(z)>\tan(y)$, making the fraction on the right hand side larger than $1$.  Thus,
$$\tan(z)-\tan(x) > \tan(x)-\tan(y).$$

By rearranging the inequality, we see that
$$\tan\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right) < \frac{\tan(z)+\tan(y)}{2},$$
which, coupled with the continuity of tangent, is sufficient to show that tangent is actually convex on this interval.